# VBA: Calculate Coverage in Two Sheets for Each Matching Code

Tags: excel, vba, code-coverage

I am trying to compute coverage for a specific matching number. I finished my code but then I realized, that I am actually comparing the same rows in different sheets, while I need to compare matching rows and columns by a corresponding number.

i.e.: for number 205090 in input sheet I need to compare values in rows with the same number in output. The issue is, that the numbers are not in order while I did my macro as they would be.

The result of this is how many weeks (a week after week) the value in output sheet is able to cover those in input one.

This is how the results should look like (output sheet). I am interested only in columns A (compared number), D (value) and E (where is the result of coverage - note: results in this column are just an example).

[output sheet with results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuFtc.png)

And here I have a sheet with the data I am comparing (input sheet), where I am interested in column A and columns G (delay) to AH (the rest I need to cover).:

[input sheet with the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dclLC.png)

This is the macro I wrote which is unfortunately not respecting the corresponding numbers.

```
Sub WeeklyCoverage()
'Define lr and r as integers; Double for decimals; String for the text
Dim lr As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim wsr As Worksheet
Dim wsc As Worksheet
Set wsr = Worksheets("SH2_results")
Set wsc = Worksheets("SH3_data")

'Turn screen updating off (to speed up computation)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Find the last row with data in column D
lr = wsr.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

'Loop through all rows in column D starting with row 2 and ending by the value of lr
For r = 2 To lr
'Compare the "COVERAGE" with the "DEALY"
'Not Covered
    If wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "NONE"
'Covered SKLUZ only
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "DELAY"
'Covered till W0
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W00"
'Covered till W1
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W01"
'Covered till W2
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W02"
'Covered till W3
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W03"
'Covered till W4
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W04"
'Covered till W5
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W05"
'Covered till W6
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W06"
'Covered till W7
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W07"
'Covered till W8
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W08"
'Covered till W9
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W09"
'Covered till W10
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W10"
'Covered till W11
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W11"
'Covered till W12
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W12"
'Covered till W13
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W13"
'Covered till W14
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W14"
'Covered till W15
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W15"
'Covered till W16
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W16"
'Covered till W17
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W17"
'Covered till W18
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W18"
'Covered till W19
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AB").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W19"
'Covered till W20
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AB").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AB").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AC").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W20"
'Covered till W21
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AB").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AC").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AB").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AC").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AD").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W21"
'Covered till W22
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AB").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AC").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AD").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AB").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AC").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AD").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AE").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W22"
'Covered till W23
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AB").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AC").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AD").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AE").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AB").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AC").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AD").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AE").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AF").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W23"
'Covered till W24
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AB").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AC").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AD").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AE").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AF").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AB").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AC").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AD").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AE").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AF").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AG").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W24"
'Covered till W25
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value >= wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AB").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AC").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AD").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AE").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AF").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AG").Value And _
    wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AB").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AC").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AD").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AE").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AF").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AG").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AH").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W25"
'Covered till W26
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value = wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AB").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AC").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AD").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AE").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AF").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AG").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AH").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W26"
'Covered till W27
    ElseIf wsr.Cells(r, "D").Value > wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "H").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "I").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "J").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "K").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "L").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "M").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "N").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "O").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "P").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Q").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "R").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "S").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "T").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "U").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "V").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "W").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "X").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Y").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "Z").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AA").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AB").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AC").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AD").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AE").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AF").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AG").Value + wsc.Cells(r, "AH").Value Then
        wsr.Cells(r, "E").Value = "W26+"

    End If
Next r

'Turn screen updating on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Is it possible to just adjust my code to do the coverage with the corresponding number, or the code is completely broken?

Comment: Probably it would be a good idea if you could provide a [mcve] with proper example data so anyone can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
For r = 2 To lr
```

use following code:

```
Set FoundCell = wsr.Range("A:A").Find(wsc.Cells(r, "A").Value)
If Not (FoundCell Is Nothing) Then
    FoundRow = FoundCell.Row

'..........................
'.. Use FoundRow as bellow:
'..........................

If wsr.Cells(FoundRow, "D").Value < wsc.Cells(r, "G").Value Then
    wsr.Cells(FoundRow, "E").Value = "NONE"

'........................
'.. your provided code
'........................

End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this actually worked very nicely. Thanks a lot for the help!